# PHP session cookie relation

Tags: php, session-cookies

session_destroy() method will delete session ID on server but what about the cookie it stores on client?
AS on every new session_start() new cookie is not set why?
What difference will this make on site?

Comment: you want to delete cookies?

Comment: You cant actually delete a cookie as such. You need to set expiry to a date that has already passed

Comment: What is the actual question sorry?

Answer (score 0):

session data is stored on the server, whereas cookies store data in the visitor’s browser.

Data stored in the cookie can be stored for months or years depending on the lifespan of the cookie.But the data in the session is lost when the web browser is closed.

Set the cookie's expiration date to a time in the past (like one second after epoch, for example).

setcookie("yourCookie", "yourValue", 0);

This will cause the cookie to expire.
 because 0 sets the cookie to expire at the end of the session.